# Using Lindeberg’s Condition together with the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

I have the following problem:

> **Problem.** Let $ (X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of independent random variables such that
>   $$
>   \mathbf{Pr} \! \left( X_{n} = \sqrt{n} + 1 \right)
> = \mathbf{Pr} \! \left( X_{n} = - \sqrt{n} - 1 \right)
> = \frac{1}{2 (\sqrt{n} + 1)^{2}}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \mathbf{Pr} \! \left( X_{n} = 0 \right) = 1 - \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n} + 1)^{2}}.
> $$
>   Then prove that the random variable $ \dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sqrt{n}} $ converges in distribution to one with a standard normal distribution.

I have to use Lindeberg’s Condition together with the Central Limit Theorem in order to solve this, but I’m stuck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ale88ssia, in order to attract attention to your problem, please make an effort to write everything down nicely first. Good typesetting almost always does wonders.

Comment: You're right! I'm Italian, my English is a bit 'lacking. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ale88ssia Could you please write down the Lindeberg's condition in the general setting. Then try to see whether it is satisfied in your particular case. In order to help you efficiently, you should be much more specific about the step where you are stuck.

Comment: I left with the desire to see if the uniform asymptotic negligibility had occurred, but I do not know how to do in practice.

Comment: @Ale88ssia Where is the problem from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to check that for a fixed positive $\varepsilon$, the convergence 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{s_n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E[X_j^2\mathbf 1\{ |X_j|\gt \varepsilon s_n \}] =0     $$
takes place, with $s_n^2=\sum_{j=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_j)=n$ in order to apply Lindeberg-Lévy-Feller theorem. 
We thus have to prove that 
$$\tag{*} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E[X_j^2\mathbf 1\{ |X_j|\gt \varepsilon \sqrt n \}]=0.$$
If $j$ is such that $\sqrt j +1\leqslant \varepsilon\sqrt n$, then $\mathbb E[X_j^2\mathbf 1\{ |X_j|\gt \varepsilon \sqrt n \}]=0$ and if $j$ is such that $\sqrt j +1\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n$, then $\mathbb E[X_j^2\mathbf 1\{ |X_j|\gt \varepsilon \sqrt n \}]=1$, hence
$$\frac 1n \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E[X_j^2\mathbf 1\{ |X_j|\gt \varepsilon \sqrt n \}]=\frac 1n\sum_{j\gt(\varepsilon\sqrt n-1)^2}^n1, $$
which does not converge to $0$.

By Theorem 2.1. page 331 of the book *Probability: A Graduate Course* by Allan Gut, since $\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_j)}{s_n^2}\to 0$, the sequence $\left(n^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j    \right)_{n\geqslant 1}  $ cannot converge to a standard normal distribution.